# Logic in Primary Jinja Template

Tags: python, architecture, flask

In my app.py file, I've stored my navigation in a dict.  The keys being the main navigation and the values being the submenus.

```
navigation = {"Search": ["Google","Yahoo","Bing"]}
```

In my layout.html template (my primary template file) I want to call the dict to generate my nav.  To me it makes sense to do this since it will be persistent across every page.  However, for every view I have I will have to define "navigation".  Which seems redundant and unecessary.

That leads me to my question, what is the appropriate way to structure the site.  I don't want to hardcode every link.  If I decide to change what the app offers, I would like the change to cascade across the site to all the other areas I'm using the navigation dict.

Example of the structure:

```
#app.py
navigation = {"Search": ["Google","Yahoo","Bing"]}
def my_view():
    return render_template('my_view.html')

#layout.html
{% for link in navigation %}
    {{ link }}
{% endfor %}
```

To resolve my issue I just have to add the navigation global to the view.

```
return render_template('my_view.html', navigation=navigation)
```

I don't want to add navigation to every view.  It feels redundant especially when you could have dozens of views.

Comment: can you define navigation outside of all views so that its basically global?

Comment: @Totem I'm pretty sure its a global.  I'll provide an example of whats happening.  If I load /login its going to call the login view which will call the login.html template which extends layout.html.  The login view sees "navigation" being used on the layout template and raises an error because the view hasn't been told what navigation means.

Comment: are you including navigation in {{ }} on your templates?

Comment: @Totem Yes.  I do something like this: {% for link in navigation %}{{ link }}{% endfor %} on my layout.html file.

Comment: If all the pages you want navigation to appear on extend layout.html, and navigation is outside of the {{% block content %}} on layout.html, then it should appear on all of those pages. If however, it's not working even on layout.html, then your problem is probably with how you are calling the dict in the template

Comment: If navigation is just like you've shown above, why not just use a list like navigation = ['Google', 'Yahoo', 'Bing']? When you do,  {% for link in navigation %}{{ link }}{% endfor %} you aren't actually providing the three search engines themselves, just the one dict entry, 'Search'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using Flask. If you add the dictionary to the app's config, you can call that in the template (Jinja recognizes the variable `config` as the app's config) without having to pass it in.

```
#app.py
app.config['navigation'] = {"Search": ["Google","Yahoo","Bing"]}
def my_view():
    return render_template('my_view.html')

#layout.html
{% for title, name in config.navigation.iteritems() %}
    {{ title }}, {{ name }}
{% endfor %}
```

(I also made your layout iterate over the dict, rather than just the keys — it looks like that is more what you want.)